# Empty C# stack trace in mono running into C++

Tags: c#, c++, mono, stack-trace

I'm running a C++ Application on Linux, that inside has a C# application running over mono.
Sometimes I get unhandled exceptions in C# code (mainly SIGSEV), so the C++ application it crashes, but unfortunately the C++ stacktrace doesn't show the C# functions where the issue is caused:

```
    Thread 2 (Thread 0xb2eda020 (LWP 5711)):
#0  0x474cc0c4 in ?? () from /lib/librt.so.1
#1  0x474cb44c in clock_nanosleep () from /lib/librt.so.1
#2  0xb6def548 in ?? () from /opt/sdw/mono/mono_small/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so.1
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

So it's impossible for me to understand where exactly the issue is happening.

Comment: Have you tried handling these exceptions? Can you run the C# program independently to debug it?

Comment: Unfortunately these exceptions are unexpected, basically bugs, but I cannot fix them if I don't know where they are... Anyway I cannot run the application independently because there is a strict dependency with C++ code that doesn't allow to do it.